# How to avoid PG::NumericValueOutOfRange when using sum function

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have method like this:

```
  def self.weighted_average(column)
    sql = "SUM(#{column} * market_cap) / SUM(market_cap) as weighted_average"
    Company.select(sql).to_a.first.weighted_average
  end
```

When the column is a `decimal`, it returns a value without problem.
But when the column is `integer`, the method ends up with a `PG::NumericValueOutOfRange` error.

Should I change column type `integer` to `decimal`, or is there a way to get the result of `sum` without changing column type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast your value to alway be a decimal value, thus no need to change the column type:

```
sql = "SUM(#{column} * CAST(market_cap as decimal(53,8))) / SUM(CAST(market_cap as decimal(53,8))) as weighted_average"
```

P.S. I would go with changing the column type - it **is consistent** then.

Answer (score 4):

You can always make `float` from your integer.

```
  def self.weighted_average(column)
    column = column.to_f
    sql = "SUM(#{column} * market_cap) / SUM(market_cap) as weighted_average"
    Company.select(sql).to_a.first.weighted_average
  end
```

Comment: `column` is column name of a model. That is just `String` or `Symbol`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to change the datatype to `decimal`. Because, when SUM gets `PG::NumericValueOutOfRange`, it means that your datatype is not sufficient. It will lead to gracefully handle this scenario, instead of a workaround.

Comment: All values in the column is small enough for the `integer`, I only get the error when using calculating function of SQL. If possible I want to avoid changing column type.

Answer (score 2):

[Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) says this about SUM() return type:

> bigint for smallint or int arguments, numeric for bigint arguments,
>   otherwise the same as the argument data type

This means that you will somehow need to change datatype that you pass to SUM. It can be one of the following:

- Alter table to change column datatype.
- Cast column to other datatype in your method.
- Create a view that casts all integer columns to numeric and use that in your method.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to place a decimal value into a integer parameter. Unless you use the ABS() value that will not be possible, unless you are 100% sure that the % value will always be 0.

Use type Float or function ABS() if you HAVE to have an INT

Answer (score 0):

Yo could try casting column to decimal

```
sql = "SUM(CAST(#{column}) AS DECIMAL * market_cap) / SUM(market_cap) as weighted_average"
```